# jaccard similarity in R

Tags: r, text, similarity, quanteda

I have a text dataframe of 792 agreements, and I have pre-processed them and converted them into a dfm. I am trying to experiment with similarity scores, and I decided to do both jaccard and cosine similarity.

When I do the cosine similarity, it takes half a minute and I get the results. But for the past two days, whenever I do the same with jaccard, my computer started whirring up and R terminates. Is there something I'm missing here? Does the jaccard function not work anymore?

I put the code below.

```
library(quanteda)
library(tidyr)

# view the resulting cosine similarity matrix
s1 <- textstat_simil(trimmed_dfm, method = "cosine", margin = "documents")

#Convert the output into a into a dataframe (first needs to be converted to a matrix)
cosine_simil_df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(s1))
#Create a column with the row names of the matrix
cosine_simil_df$PTA1 <- row.names(cosine_simil_df)
#Use pivot longer gather verb to reshape the data in Tidy format
cosine_simil_df_final <- pivot_longer(cosine_simil_df, cols = -PTA1, names_to = "PTA2", values_to = "similarity")
head(cosine_simil_df_final)

##### Let's try with the Jaccard similarity
s2<- textstat_simil(trimmed_dfm, method = "jaccard", margin = "documents")
#this line is when it all goes wrong

jaccard_simil_df<- as.data.frame(as.matrix(s2))

jaccard_simil_df$PTA1 <- row.names(jaccard_simil_df)
```

Comment: You need to supply some more details about `s2` and about your machine, but in short, it's likely exploding when you convert from the sparse matrix object that is `s2` into first a (regular, dense) matrix and then to a data.frame. Also, no need to convert to a matrix first, just convert using `as.data.frame(s2)`.

Comment: @KenBenoit Thank you so much for your comment! It;s great to get feedback from one of the creators of textstat_simil. I have adjusted the code so I don't convert it first into a matrix. I am using a HP CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz Base speed: 3.19 GHz, and s2 is basically running a large dfm that has 2226712752 elements (517.4 MB). My main concern is why does it work very quickly for the cosine method but crashes everytime with the jaccard.

Answer (score 1):

I did not optimize function for the Jaccard similarity as much as for the cosine similarity. You could try `drop0 = TRUE` to reduce memory usage. `proxyC::simil()` is the package behind `textstat_simil()`.

```r
proxyC::simil(matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2), 
              matrix(c(2, 2, 0, 0), nrow = 2), method = "jaccard")
#> 2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
#>         
#> [1,] 1 1
#> [2,] 0 0
proxyC::simil(matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2), 
              matrix(c(2, 2, 0, 0), nrow = 2), method = "jaccard", drop0 = TRUE)
#> 2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
#>         
#> [1,] 1 1
#> [2,] . .
```